# Blink leds in many patterns (EMBEDDED)

Tags: if-statement, embedded, led

I would like to blink leds in many patterns. I wanna ask if my code is a "programmer solution". I create an incrementing variable named "counter" and switch LED state if counter reach some value. I am not sure about using equal operator in if condition like *if(counter == 20)*. How to avoid jumping into LED switching part every counter increment another way?

Can someone rewrite this program into "shape"?

Another solution is to change a timer value to next overflow, is it better?

```
if(timer_10ms_flag ==  1) {
  timer_10ms_flag ==  0;

  if((counter > 100) || (reset_counter == 1)) {
    counter = 0;
    reset_counter = 0;
  }

  if(mode == 0) {
    if(counter == 0) {
      LED_ON;    
    }

    if(counter == 20) {
      LED_OFF;
    }
  }

  if(mode == 1) {
    if(counter == 0) {
      LED_ON;    
    }

    if(counter == 10) {
      LED_OFF;
    }

    if(counter == 20) {
      LED_ON;    
    }

    if(counter == 40) {
      LED_OFF;
    }
  }

  counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will become cumbersome and difficult to maintain if you were to have "many patterns". In fact it is that already and you only have two.

Rather then encoding your patterns in the control flow logic of the code, you would do better to make it *data driven* and encode your pattern in a look-up table.  You then use the *same* code to execute any pattern.

Other improvements are:

- Use Booleans for flags rather then integers (`#include <stdbool.h>` and use the `bool` type).
- Simplify your `counter` cycle code using the `%` operator. Your original code cycles through 101 steps.  That may have been intentional, but it seems unlikely.  My solution below has 100 counts - 0 to 99.
- The is insufficient context in the question fragment to know what `timer_10ms_flag` is for but that can most likely also be Boolean. The code fragment has an error at `timer_10ms_flag == 0;`. The statement has no effect. (`==` where `=` was intended).

```
  if( timer_10ms_flag ) 
  {
      timer_10ms_flag = false ;
  }
  
  // The patterns 
  static const int pattern[][100] = { {0, 20, -1},            // Mode 0 pattern 
                                      {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, -1} // Mode 1 pattern
                                    } ;
  static int pattern_idx = 0 ;
  static bool led_on = false ;

  // Cycle 0 to 99, or reset to zero on request
  counter = reset_counter ? 0 : counter % 100 ;
  reset_counter = false ;
  if( counter == 0 ) led_on = false ;


  // If at the toggle point...
  if( counter == pattern[mode][pattern_idx] )
  {
      // Toggle the LED
      led_on = !led_on ;
      if( led_on ) LED_ON else LED_OFF ;
      
      // Get next toggle point
      pattern_idx++ ;
      if( pattern[mode][pattern_idx] < 0 )
      {
          pattern_idx = 0 ;
      }
  }

  // Next count
  counter++;
```

Comment: Many thx for answer, the array idea I was thinking about also. I have doubt about one thing: the LED toggling. The next LED state is dependent on previous LED state. So if microcontroller become out of order during long run (like one year), the LED state can become inverted until someone will reset it or power it down. So maybe it is better to synchronize the LED state everytime the counter reach maximum.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický : Yes, but not for the reason you suggest.  The pattern will be inverted every other cycle if there are an odd number of toggle points, and will invert in any case if the LED is on when `reset_counter` is set. Added: `if( counter == 0 ) led_on = false ;`.  Obviously I cannot test this code or see the context in which you will use it - the correctness of the code is not the take-home here, but that was a clear error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

- For each sequence, define an array of 10ms intervals, such as:

  `const bool SEQUENCE [n] = { true, false, false, true, false ... };`

  Where true means LED on and false means off.
- Set up a periodic timer interrupt that triggers every 10ms.
- From inside the ISR:

  ```
  const bool SEQUENCE [n] = { true, false, false, true, false ... };

  void timer_ISR (void)
  {
    static uint_fast8_t counter=0;

    if(SEQUENCE[counter % n])
      LED = ON;
    else
      LED = OFF;

    counter++;  
  }
  ```

That's pretty much it. We actually don't care about the value of the counter, we just let it run. Unsigned integers in C have a well-defined wrap-around to zero when they go beyond max, so we don't need to keep track of it.

The code can be optimized ever so slightly by swapping the bool array for a bit-field, in case flash memory is tight.

---

Note: be careful when doing port I/O from inside an ISR though. If other parts of the program share the same port I/O register, you can get very subtle race condition bugs on the hardware register itself.

Comment: When I think on/off, I think xor.  Gets rid of that pesky else statement.  Of course that means absolutely nothing in terms of code performance or anything, but still... xor :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan It isn't obvious if "led on" is just a simple pin toggle or something more intricate. The OP wrote them as obscure macros in some secret macro language.